# Questions in "close" review queue with no close votes

Tags: bug

In the past few weeks I've ocassionally seen questions on the "close" queue that don't have any actual close votes. Has anybody else seen this? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've noticed that too. I think it's because we are getting more users being active on the site. [See this question on the main SE meta site to answer why it's happening.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159944/questions-with-no-close-votes-appearing-in-the-close-vote-queue)

> Any time a user without the vote-to-close privilege flags the question for a canned vote-to-close reason, it is automatically added to the close votes review queue as a way of reviewing the flag. The reason they used for the flag is the one presented at the top. I can only imagine that it being removed from the queue by too many "Leave Open" votes would automatically dismiss the flag as well, but I cannot confirm that. The flag is dismissed if the question gets closed, though.
>
> You'll also notice that in cases where someone flagged as an exact duplicate, their flag is included in the count when selecting which question is the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. It's good to know it's not a bug and to understand what's going on.